# How to query/make a report for All fields on All objects?

Tags: soql, custom-object, custom-field, custom-reports

We have a very old org with many objects and unused fields, how can i query/make a report to find all fields for all custom objects, and order them by lastmodified date?

the goal is to find which fields have not been touched so that the company can look at wether or not those fields are necessary

here is what i have so far for the objects,

```
SELECT QualifiedApiName, LastModifiedDate FROM EntityDefinition where (IsCustomizable = true AND IsLayoutable=true) order by LastModifiedDate
```

Any advice for retrieving the fields for all objects and ordering by last modified date??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [Field Trip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4). It may not serve your needs, so try it out in a Sandbox first, but I do think it's a pretty decent product (note: I'm not affiliated with this package, just a previous user).

Answer (score 0):

The free Heroku app [Salesforce Schema Lister](https://schemalister.herokuapp.com/) is another good alternative.

> Salesforce Schema Lister : This tool uses the Salesforce Metadata API to build a list of objects, fields and field attributes from within your Salesforce Org.

It is part of [Toolkit for Salesforce](https://cloudtoolkit.co/) app series

(Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with these apps)